# modify template file from web and save it to local using HTML5, JavaScript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a site, where some settings, set up by a client, may be written to a file, that is not located in the client's filesystem, but is a file of my project. Then this file, with some parts of it overwritten, must be saved to local storage.

*For example:*

**template_file.txt**  contents:

> My favourite color is WHITE.
>   I like GREEN tea with lemon.
>   Leaves on the trees are GREEN.

**Web page**  initially has something like:
[Empty Text Field 1 Here]
[Empty Text Field 2 here]
[Empty Text Field 3 here]
Filename: [Empty Filename Field here]
{OK Button}
{Save File Button}

(Text of **template_file.txt** is not visible to the client, but is included into the website's project.)

Client's input:
[red]
[black]
[Empty Text Field 3 here]
Filename: [generated_file]
{OK Button}
{Save File Button}

(Field 3 left unchanged, {OK Button} *clicked*.)

**generated_file.txt**  contents:

> My favourite color is red.
>   I like black tea with lemon.
>   Leaves on the trees are GREEN.

({Save File Button} *clicked*. => Site proposes to save **generated_file.txt** to local filesystem.)

I have found a tutorial on how to save all the text from a textarea to file here:
[Loading, Editing, and Saving a Text File in HTML5 Using Javascript](https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/)

But I have no idea how to generate file, using partly overwritten template file from web for it. Any tips on how to do it (if it's actually possible) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I suppose this is well possible, I would suggest it would be way 'easier' to do this with a server side programming language like php. I'll try to explain why: it's the 'classic' server-client-dilema.

1. client / user makes a request / submits a form to the server
2. server then reacts on that input, e.g. composes html and css files and sends everything back to client

If you want to manipulate a file according to user input, doing that on the server would be the 'natural' location. Otherwise you would probably need ajax, javascript or the like to do this in the browser (*if* you dynamically want to include server files / server data).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at client side frameworks like [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/)